# Why doesn't using a ternary ?: in CoffeeScript produce an error?

Tags: coffeescript

Ok, so [CoffeeScript doesn't support ternary operators](http://coffeescript.org/#conditionals).

But why doesn't it blow up in my face when I try to use it?

```
coffee> x = (true ? 1 : 2)
true
```

What exactly is the computation there? Why doesn't it yield a compile error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question mark checks if the value in front exists, then it returns it, otherwise it returns the second value. `a ? b` would return a if a is not undefined, otherwise it would return b. So we got `true ? ( 1 : 2 )` with added parentheses. It checks if true is not undefined (which it is not) and returns it, otherwise it would return a new object `{1:2}`.

The compiled javascript looks like

```
x = typeof true !== "undefined" && true !== null ? true : {
  1: 2
};
```

Answer (score 3):

In the future, look at the compiled JavaScript.

This is perfectly valid CoffeeScript, it just doesn't do what you think it should.

You're using the existential operator, `?`, and, if the operand of `?` is null or undefined, returning an object with a property `1` and a value of `2`.

More plainly, it's doing this:

```
x = true ? { 1: 2 }
```

Or

```
x = (if true then true else {1: 2})
```